# como mostrar dados de apenas um usuario cadastrado no mongoose

Tags: node.js, express.js, mongoose, handlebars.js

boa noite, estou tentando desenvolver um aplicação e estou travado,
gostaria de saber como faço para mostrar dados apenas do usuário logado, segue o código

```
gameCtrl.renderHome = async (req, res) => {
const user = await User.find().lean()
res.render('game/home', {user})}
```

estou usando handlebars como engine, e na parte de html está assim:

```
{{#each user}}
 <p>{{power}}</p>
 {{/each}}
```

sendo que no meu app está listando no caso o dado "power" de todos os usuários do banco de dados
e gostaria de mostrar apenas do usuário q está logado no momento, alguém pode me ajudar, sei que o erro está na rota, sou leigo em desenvolvimento e não consegui achar uma maneira para fazer isso.

na aplicação aparece

PODER: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;

onde os "0" significam o "poder" de cada usuário q eu tenho no banco de dados e eu gostar de mostrar apenas o do usuário logado.

Comment: em tese, eu acredito q tenho q pegar o _ID gerado ao criar a conta, mas como disse, sou leigo e não consegui fazer isso

Answer (score 0):

Acho que descobri, caso alguem consiga me confirmar se está correto ficarei agradecido..

```
gameCtrl.renderHome = async (req, res) => {
const user = await User.find({_id: req.user._id}).lean()
res.render('game/home', {user})}
```

Depois de uma noite de pesquisas e tentativas após passar o {_id: req.user._id} dentro do .find() o retorno no app foi de apenas um 0, aparentemente apenas do usuário logado. Se alguem puder me confirmar se isso está correto ficarei muito Grato, desde já obrigado a todos!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).